# How to export Laravel database in a .sql script

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm working on a **Laravel** project and i need to export my **migrations** and **seeds** into a .sql script.

I tried using this command but it only export tables structures and not records.

> *php artisan migrate --pretend --no-ansi > migrate.sql*

How can i export tables and tables content in a .sql file?

Comment: Try adding `--seed`

Comment: Adding --seed i can't see MySQL queries, but only "Seeding: tableName"